# Centos iptables fails with docker rules

Tags: docker, centos, centos7, iptables

I have installed a docker service:

```
docker run --rm --name some-nginx -d -p 8080:80 nginx:stable-alpine
```

Then I have added iptable rule for it:

```
PORT=8080
 /sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport $PORT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED      -j ACCEPT
 /sbin/iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --sport $PORT -m state --state ESTABLISHED  -j ACCEPT
```

When I try to check if port is open it says it is open:

```
$netstat -anp | grep 8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      11211/docker-proxy
```

When I try to investigete more it seems still open:

```
 iptables-save | grep 8080
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:80
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8080 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

I see docker added  some rules but  my rules are present.

The problem is I cant connect to nginx at given port!

```
telnet XX.XX.XX.XX 8080
Trying XX.XX.XX.XX...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

When I turn off iptables it works even with browser giving nginx start page.

**How to enable iptables or docker to work with given port?**

Answer (score 0):

i have some pages you can read.:

```
https://fralef.me/docker-and-iptables.html
https://riptutorial.com/docker/topic/9201/iptables-with-docker
```

I have also a linux, try this here:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport xxx -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport xxx -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
or
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport xxx -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport xx -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Wired this is that my rules are not needed it works only with the first rule added by docker. But I have other file with rules applied every minute. Now running that rules that do not deal with pot `8080` brakes this docker rule. However tihs rule is still present but its like it not used after applying my iptables script from bash script.

Comment: I have to restart the entire docker and start the container so the rules again become working

Comment: Ok now I found out that my script was using the `/sbin/iptables -F` and flushed some docker rules too. But how to flush only non-docker rules?

Comment: Well I found out that `iptables -F INPUT` and `iptables -F OUTPUT` must be explicit and remaining chanins should stay eg FORWARD should not be flushed because docker uses this chain.